# How can I add ".html" to the end of a single URL on a Wordpress website?

Tags: php, facebook, htaccess

The sites url structure is as follows:

```
www.sitename.com/mypage/page/
```

I would like only one certain page on the site to resolve as:

```
www.sitename.com/mypage/page.html
```

This is so that when I run the link through the Facebook Sharing debugger at:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
```

... the link works correctly.  Currently, Facebook appears to strip query string parameters on pages shared that do not resolve as `.html`.

Comment: _“Currently, Facebook appears to strip query string parameters on pages shared that do not resolve as .html”_ - I think that might rather be a problem of your Open Graph meta tags. Make sure you set the og:url correctly.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule - make a rule then parse the queries to handle the template loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quickly by creating a rule in .htaccess.

Log in to Wordpress and go to the page you want to link to.

Then click "preview changes".

Look for the preview_id parameter in the url.

And use this id after de index.php?p= in the .htaccess like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^mypage/page.html$ index.php?p=262 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END Wordpress
```

Comment: Keep in mind that PHP can rewrite the .htaccess. By example when using WP SuperCache. So it is not the best solution. But it works. There are several ways to add this rule permanently to your htaccess. If needed i can help you with that too.

Comment: Hey Alain, Thank you for your solution! I would be interested to know how to add this rule permanently also.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely works without .html, maybe try it like this:

```
www.sitename.com/mypage/page?param1=xxx
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment, is there an easy way to do this for only 1 URL in Wordpress?  I don't want to remove the trailing slash from all url's on an existing site.

Comment: only 1 URL? That may not be easy, of course you can hack it somehow, but that´s never a good idea...